# Docker Desktop How do I copy a dir from host to container once the dir is modified with PowerShell? (host windows container ubuntu)

Tags: linux, windows, docker, powershell

I need to create a script that will be executed once every time there is a change in some dir in windows and the script should copy files from that dir to a specific dir in a Linux container which has a shared directory between the container and the host.

my container cannot access the internet at all.
this is the only solution I have managed to pull off by now from the Linux machine which isn't exactly what I need it to do:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true; do
    cp -r /home/some-folder /var/atlassian/application-data/jira/scripts/ && chown -R jira:jira /var/atlassian/application-data/jira
    sleep 10
done
```

as you can understand, the code is running from the Linux machine every 10 seconds and not when I modify the Dir.

your assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: use `inotifywait`

Comment: The container doesn't have inotifywait by default.
I need something that is coming out of the box from Linux or using a powershell.
because the windows host has internet access and the container doesn't, then I think my best solution is to use powershell.